# How do I make my IP address appear it's from Japan while I am from India?

Tags: windows-7

I logged into a site and said I am from Japan. I don't want to reveal I am from India.  They can see my IP address is from India. How can I change my IP so it appears I am using internet from Japan? Please be specific because I am clueless with computers!

Comment: You need to get a VPN hosted in japan. You can try to find a [free one](https://www.google.com/search?q=vpn+japan+free) but they are usually crap.

Comment: @Nifle - Or a `Proxy`, but again, the free ones are pretty useless.

Comment: @nerdwaller - Yeah, you are correct. But I wouldn't trust a proxy not to sniff my traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Hidemyass has one Japanese proxy server listed (with instructions at the bottom) here: https://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-225413.

If you want something more seamless, fast, and secure, you could pay for Hidemyass's VPN service, and select from one of the 248 Japanese servers to use. Here's a link: https://hidemyass.com/vpn/

Comment: How much it will cost me to use this Hidemyass's Vpn?